# Access Denied when creating SQLite DB file

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to create the database file to initialize it but I'm getting "Access Denied" error during execution. I think is something related with permissions but I'm not able to find any information that could fix it, since every guide I check does it the same way. 
This is an UWP application using C# and SQLite library. Thanks in advance for the help.

In the past I've tried to also create json file with other methods but I've never been able to create a file from a UWP application

Code that raises an error:

```
private const string DBName = "data.sqlite";

if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(DBName)))
{
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(DBName);
    RecentlyCreated = true;
}
```

Error message:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\Pass\Pass\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\dataAccount.sqlite'
>   is denied.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UWP has a very limited access to the user filesystem, as it described at [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) specification. You can use user libraries (downloads, documents) for storing the data (after allowing an access in `appxmanifest` file) or application data store (more viable in your case). Try to define `DBName` as

```
string DBName = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\data.sqlite";
```

Or you can allow `broadFileSystemAccess` using link above

Comment: The default working directory is the install location, which is read - only. Also be sure to check the SQLite docs re: temp directory.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, I've been quite busy. Anyway, your help was extreamely usefull, thanks a lot!!